# Minimum nurses by shift

Tags: job-scheduling, constraint-programming, or-tools

I'm trying to play with the first example of this link : https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling

I would like to have at least two nurses by shifts.
So I modified the line :

```
model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 1)
```

By :

```
model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) == 2)
```

And I increased the number of nurses to 8.

Unfortunately, the program doesn't find any solutions.
But it should, there are enough nurses for this.
Do you have an idea ? Thanks!

PS : If I set the number of days to 1, it works, but if it's superior to 1, it found nothing.

Comment: Staff need holidays and time (10 hours per 24) away from work. employ more staff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this example is problematic and needs to be updated. The problem is that it assumes that the number of possible shifts is equal to the number of nurses, and thus each shift is performed by exactly one nurse.

For a more interesting starting point, I suggest you look at:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py

This example is more complex and includes specific constraints that are better suited to shift scheduling.